# How to stop Power Automate from creating the same event when using recurrence?

Tags: excel, outlook, power-automate, power-platform

Picture of flow:

[image: Picture of flow]

So I have an excel timetable with title, startdate, enddate. I'm able to use Power Automate to create calendar events based off that table every hour. But it is creating the same event over and over again now regardless if it is new, old, or updated events. How do I make it only create a new event if it is new or updated.

I am currently using a condition to check for matching events but it is not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You’re on the right track so why isn’t your condition working? Provide more info and maybe we can help.

Comment: I'm unsure as to why its not working.